# Devise confirmable confirmation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

A lot of users (but not all) are facing this problem in my current Rails app using devise with confirmable module.

They try to login after confirming their account. 
But after entering in the password, they are prompted with the following 2 messages:

"You have to confirm your account before continuing.

Your account was successfully confirmed."

which are contradictory.

My database shows all such users as confirmed. On their end, this error goes away once they delete their cache and cookies, and they are able to then log in.

This is the part of the code that I have modified for ConfirmationController

```
class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  def show
    self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :confirmed) if is_flashing_format?
      sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource) # <= THIS LINE ADDED
      # respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource) } # <= THIS LINE R
    else
      respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
    end
  end
```